# Xcode location services nearest

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new here:)

So basically, is there any way that throughout xcode 6 i can implement a code that can identify US & European stores....

Is it very difficult

I thought about using the location service and moving to find nearest stores but that will not be handy.... Also ( for example lets say that the app found that you somewhere and creates a list of table view of all you stores found ( and if it possible to give directions to this store)

Can it be done?

Thanks for the help

Comment: try [google API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) for search near by places

Comment: Can i implement the code into xcode ,?

Comment: yes, proceed as you done JSON parsing but put URL of googleAPI with parameters.

Comment: Have a look at the foursquare api: [FS API](https://developer.foursquare.com/start). You just send a URL Request to their service and they will give you a nice json with all the stores around you. After that you can navigate to this place via Apple's Map Kit.

Comment: Can you help me a little through out steps on what to do ( i am new in programming) - sorry :(

Comment: I need help please : i found this also :http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift

Comment: I have a problem here : Once again, select the Feed Me project at the top of the Project Navigator, only this time, choose the Feed Me Project rather than the target. Select the Build Settings tab, and in Other Linker Flags add -ObjC as shown below: =  I go there but i cannot add obj-c

Answer (score 0):

[Google's Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) seems to be the best solution in this case. Create one application in Google Console. You'll get one API key, which is to be used while making the API calls.

To be more specific, you can use [NearBySearch API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

Comment: and then implement it to my xcode app? How do i ?, i have made a app in google console

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit)

Comment: i found this but i have to download the project? http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift

Comment: At the end, you can have the project downloaded once you have it's understanding.

Comment: the problem is that i need all the .swift files to make the app, but i want to change them

Comment: You can also code in Objective C. The Objective C version of the above tutorial is also available on the same web site.

Comment: Is the one that you posted that it has the code in objective -c the other one is in swift right?

Comment: [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit) is the same tutorial in objective C. There isn't any requirement to download any of the Swift files.

Comment: Also i dont want to ask another questions : Does anyone knows how to implement a barcode scanner in my app ( i found some ) , but what i really need is a ready library with many add barcodes? If so can somebody tell me how to do it ( If found zbar to be good , but how will i inplement the code into my app and the libraries used for identification